# using mongoaggregation how to check every day data updated or not

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, monodevelop

My mongodb data number of collection are there how to check all collection at a time with data insert or not
iam trying this code i got it one collection data but how to check numberof collection data at a time.

```
db.collection.find({  
   $where:function () {  
      return Date.now() - this._id.getTimestamp() < (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1:**

If you want to apply a query to all collections in the MongoDb database you can issue a query like:;

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(n) { 
  print(n + ":" + db[n].count());
});
```

The query above will give you a count for all the collections in the MongoDB database.

**Original Post**

If your business problem is about knowing how many records were inserted by day, based on the timestamp, you can use the map reduce framework to count the number of records per day using the ObjectId stored in the `_id` field. This aggregation will contain all days in which data was inserted.

You will have to have a JS function which converts the ID to a date string, to save it in the db.system.js collection and then execute a `mapReduce` call on the corresponding collection.

Here is the code for this:

```
var dateFromObjectId = function (objectId) {
  var d = objectId.getTimestamp();
  return (d.getYear() + 1900) + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate();
};

db.system.js.save({ "_id": "dateFromObjectId", "value": dateFromObjectId });

db.metrics.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(dateFromObjectId(this._id), 1);
    },
    function(key, values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

This will print something like this:

```
  {
    "results": [{
            "_id": "2018-0-2",
            "value": 10628
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-0-3",
            "value": 13835
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-0-4",
            "value": 11624
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-0-5",
            "value": 8983
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-0-6",
            "value": 1076
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-1-0",
            "value": 25771
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-1-1",
            "value": 20498
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-1-2",
            "value": 4703
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-1-3",
            "value": 12738
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-1-4",
            "value": 23840
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-1-5",
            "value": 25888
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-1-6",
            "value": 25377
        },
        {
            "_id": "2018-2-0",
            "value": 2183
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis": 5528,
    "counts": {
        "input": 599471,
        "emit": 599471,
        "reduce": 1941,
        "output": 63
    },
    "ok": 1
  }
```

Comment: sorry i con''t understand  any possible write the only aggregation

Comment: @VARUN Sorry, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @ gil.fernandes my robomongo database number of collections are there but how to check every day how many number of collecton added new data base  in each collecton ...using mongo db aggregation how to check all collection at a time

Comment: @VARUN Please see my updated answer. I tried to explain how to fire queries to all collections at a time.